# Class "implements" another class -- getting errors. Looking for clarification

Tags: typescript

Can somebody explain why [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Test%20%7B%0D%0A%09someObj%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09someString%3A%20'this'%7C'that'%7C'the%20other'%0D%0A%09%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Test2%20implements%20Test%20%7B%0D%0A%09someObj%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09someString%3A%20'this'%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D) is incorrect?

Here it is again.

```
// This is defined in a d.ts file. 
class Test {
    someObj: {
        someString: 'this'|'that'|'the other'
    };
}

// This is me actually using the class.
class Test2 implements Test {
    someObj = {
        someString: 'this'
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a bug, as it does not work even when `extends` is used instead of `implements`, but this works just fine:

```
class Test {
    someObj: {
        someString: 'this'|'that'|'the other'
    };
}

class Test2 extends Test {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.someObj = {
            someString: 'this'
        }
    }
}
```

And both compile into the same js:

```
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
};
var Test = (function () {
    function Test() {
    }
    return Test;
}());
var Test2 = (function (_super) {
    __extends(Test2, _super);
    function Test2() {
        _super.call(this);
        this.someObj = {
            someString: 'this'
        };
    }
    return Test2;
}(Test));
```

(except that in your code it's: `_super.apply(this, arguments)`).

You can post an issue on [their github](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues), if you do please post the url as a comment as I'd like to follow on that.

If you really intended to use `implements` and not `extends` then using a constructor won't solve your issue but doing this will:

```
type SomeObj = {
    someString: 'this'|'that'|'the other'
};

class Test {
    someObj: SomeObj;
}

class Test2 implements Test {
    someObj: SomeObj = {
        someString: 'this'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the looking into this further Nitzan. Here's the issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10071